# when to write class as generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have class lets say

```
Class Rectange{
    int height;
    int side;
}
```

what all are the cases in which I can make this class as generic? How to identify that we want to write a generic class?
Probably a practical example will be good.

**Update**

1. what are the use cases to make our class generics?
2. Real life scenarios where we will use generics?

Comment: Probably [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: The Most practicle Example in my **opinion** is the `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-life example: I need a simple processor which will take many values and return the highest, the lowest and median, based on natural ordering. I don't know which type of objects it will operate (or I do, but don't want to restrict it to using only one particular type), and I don't want it to accept `Object` to avoid casting. So I make this class and all its methods generic:

```
public class MySimpleProcessor<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public void putValue(T value) { /*...*/ }
    public T getHighest()         { /*...*/ }
    public T getLowest()          { /*...*/ }
    public T getMedian()          { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now, `MySimpleProcessor` can operate on any comparable objects:

```
MySimpleProcessor<String> stringProcessor;             // will accept and return strings
MySimpleProcessor<Integer> intProcessor;               // will accept and return integers
MySimpleProcessor<AnotherComparable> anotherProcessor; // will operate on some other type
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make this class generic, if you want any of the mentioned *types* to be variable.

Currently your class only contains references to the type `int`. If you want to make this type variable, you can use this code:

```
class Rectange<T extends Number> {
    T height;
    T side;
}
```

Afterwards you can then make instances, that either use `Integer`s or other types to store `height` and `side`:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectange<Integer> intRect = new Rectange<>();
        intRect.height = 12;
        Integer intHeight = intRect.height; // no cast needed, the height is guaranteed to be an int

        Rectange<Double> dblRect = new Rectange<>();
        dblRect.height = 1.20076;
        Double doubleHeight = dblRect.height; // this time, height is guaranteed to be an double
    }
}
```

As a **conclusion** I would say: Use generics, if you have to make the types variable. So using generics *can* be usefull, depending on your use case.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I can make sense, depending on the use case.

Comment: Better, but I still don't understand why not simply use `Number` for properties :) anyway, +1 for well-explained answer

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I added the usage of the fields - to show the benefits: No casting required when accessing the fields. Thanks for noticing (and for upvoting :) ).

Comment: This I understood that If I want to make my type as variable then we can use generics, but do you have some practical examples or a flow chart kind of this so that I can make decision to write a generic class?

Comment: @eatSleepCode Generics help you to avoid type casts. If you can find a solution without using generics and casts, then do not use generics.

Comment: @eatSleepCode real-life example can be any collection from `java.util`: if you don't know which type of objects your class will work with, make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

Don`t use OOP as ideology, but rather like a tool that is here to help You solve problems. First write two classes and if they are using identical fields, create additional base class to derive from. 
Example for graphics editing program:

```
Class PaintTool{
    protected int r, g, b;

}
Class Rectangle extends PaintTool{
    float x, y, width, height;
}

Class Brush extends PaintTool{
    float radius;
}
```